# How can I get a PeerInfo from a Host?

Tags: go, libp2p, go-libp2p

I'm trying to get a `PeerInfo` from a `libp2p.Host` instance.  I'm able to get a list of `multiaddr.Multiaddr`s by calling `Host.Addrs()`, but I'm unable to convert these into a valid `peerstore.PeerInfo`.

Here is my attempt, which panics with the error `panic: invalid p2p multiaddr`.

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/SentimensRG/ctx"
    "github.com/SentimensRG/ctx/sigctx"

    libp2p "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p"
    ps "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-peerstore"
)

var c = ctx.AsContext(sigctx.New())

func main() {
    h0, err := libp2p.New(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }    

    addr0 := h0.Addrs()[1]

    _, err := ps.InfoFromP2pAddr(addr0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

#### How can I get a `peerstore.PeerInfo` from a `libp2p.Host`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PeerInfo](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-peerstore/blob/e200f3a5c18ecb223bbc1d0ad9316641fa0dbb94/peerinfo.go#L16) is a struct that encapsulates a peer ID and its multiaddrs. To build a PeerInfo from a Host easily, you can simply do the following:

```
pi := PeerInfo{
        ID: host.ID(),
        Addrs: host.Addrs(),
}
```

`pstore.InfoFromP2pAddr()` requires a multiaddr with a `p2p` or `ipfs` component in order to populate the `PeerInfo.ID` element.

That said, we could definitely make it easier to obtain a `PeerInfo` from a `Host`. I'll work on it ;-)

Comment: "I'll work on it ;-)"  <=  this is why I like libp2p :)

Comment: damn you're fast! Can't wait to contribute to this project :)